# "Can't check signature: public key not found" while upgrading, why?

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10. I'm unable to do via GUI.

[ The reason why I'm unable to do so:

Via software updater, I proceed ahead and click upgrade (for upgrading my OS). I authenticate by providing my password. Then it proceeds and downloads upgrade tool. That time only (while downloading the tool) error message comes "system program problem detected". It then doesn't proceed ahead and I click to report the problem ]

So, I tried via command line but here also I couldn't succeed upgrading my OS. 
For the same I ran

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then I ran

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And then:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]                                                                                                 
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,135 kB]                                                                                                        
Fetched 1,135 kB in 6s (32.9 kB/s)                                                                                                   
authenticate 'saucy.tar.gz' against 'saucy.tar.gz.gpg' 
gpg exited 2
Debug information: 


gpg: Signature made Friday 01 November 2013 10:34:27 AM IST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found

Authentication failed
Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server. 
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$
```

Please suggest how to go ahead and upgrade my OS.

Comment: Why are you unable to do it via the GUI? Which error messages do you get there?

Comment: @l0b0 I have updated my Q with the reply to your Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 437D05B5
apt-get update
```

Otherwise you might be able to use [this blogpost](http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=84):

> **The solution** 
>   After a bit of head scratching, it seems the simple solution is to delete all of the GPG keys in /etc/apt and re-run apt-get update.
>
> ```
> cd /etc/apt
> sudo mkdir gpgbackup
> sudo mv *.gpg gpgbackup/
> gpg --export -a 437D05B5 | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

(added backing up instead of plain `rm`)

Comment: You have missed one important point in your codes. You have taken backup but missed deleting the gpg files. After deleting the files, I have also get rid of the annoying messages " no public key ....". I'm trying whether now I can upgrade my OS to Ubuntu 13.10. I will update after that.

Comment: Thank you very very much. It's working. I'm able to upgrade my current Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. I canceled the upgrade as it's going to take many hours due to my slow Internet connectivity. I will do at night so that when I wake up tomorrow morning it would have completed. Great Thom Wiggers!! One thing I would like to add: While upgrading, it popped up a message "Some 3rd party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager."

Comment: That's ppa's you installed and maybe some software from the software center. Just do exactly what it said in the popup to reenable them.

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 437D05B5 3E5C1192
sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 437D05B5
sudo gpg --no-default-keyring -a --export 437D05B5 | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ~/.gnupg/trustedkeys.gpg --import -
```

Then, 2 options:

Option A:

> Use `sudo update-manager -d` and you'll get there by GUI.

Option B (command line only):

> Install the update-manager-core package if it is not already installed:
>
> sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
>   Edit the file /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades,
>
> sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
>   and set `Prompt=normal` below `#           determine if a newer release is available.`. This would look like this:
>
> > ```
> > #  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader 
> > #           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after > >     #           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be > >     #           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS 
> > #           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to 
> > #           determine if a newer release is available. 
> > Prompt=normal
> > ```
>
> Now run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and follow the instructions.

Comment: What it means please:  ` set Prompt=normal under # determine if a newer release is available.` That file contains all sentences with # in the beginning (i.e. they are commented) except the last one. The last sentence is: `Prompt=normal`

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything as `Prompt` already equals `normal`..

Comment: Check out my edit.

Comment: As that file remains unchanged, what procedure you told is what I had tried and mentioned in my Q. Just now also again I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` then `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. The same error I got as shown in my Q.

Comment: What about way A?

Comment: Option A is via software updater (GUI). I had tried this earlier also but gave an error as mentioned in my Q. I have run it just now also. I clicked upgrade. It started downloading the upgrade tool. Then the window vanished and after some time got the same error message "system program problem detected".

Comment: Check my edit again.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. The last edit is what will work as it seems to be much similar to the answer I accepted (of Thom Wiggers).